# Logs not generating on migration from Log4j 2.17.2 to 2.18.0

Tags: java, log4j2

My project has multiple modules, which are interacting and dependent on each other. My app is working on Log4j 2.17.2 logs are generating fine. But when I'm migrating to 2.18.0, the logs stopped generating. What is the possible error? Please help.
NOTE: I can't upload code as its secure work.

I can't understand the problem, and I'm expecting the logs to get printed on 2.18.0 as well.

**I applied -DLog4j.debug=true**
**My stdout with 2.17.2 -**

```
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Lookup' found 17 plugins  
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Lookup' found 17 plugins  
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Lookup' found 17 plugins  
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Lookup' found 17 plugins  
DEBUG StatusLogger Using configurationFactory org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory@71248c21    
WARN StatusLogger Error parsing URI C:/-------project path----/log4j2-idp.xml   
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Lookup' found 17 plugins  
DEBUG StatusLogger Closing FileInputStream java.io.FileInputStream@59717824 
DEBUG StatusLogger Apache Log4j Core 2.17.2 initializing configuration XmlConfiguration[location=C:/-----Project path------/log4j2-idp.xml] 
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Core' found 129 plugins   
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Level' found 0 plugins    
DEBUG StatusLogger Building Plugin[name=property, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Property]. 
TRACE StatusLogger TypeConverterRegistry initializing.  
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'TypeConverter' found 26 plugins   
DEBUG StatusLogger createProperty(name="fileName", value="idp", value="idp")    
DEBUG StatusLogger Building Plugin[name=properties, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.PropertiesPlugin].   
DEBUG StatusLogger configureSubstitutor(={fileName=idp}, Configuration(C:/-----project path -------log4j2-idp.xml))
```

**My stdout after 2.18.0**

```
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Lookup' found 17 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Lookup' found 17 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Lookup' found 17 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Lookup' found 17 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger Using configurationFactory org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory@345965f2
WARN StatusLogger Error parsing URI C:/-----project path ----/log4j2-tomcat.xml
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Lookup' found 17 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger Closing FileInputStream java.io.FileInputStream@6b53e23f
DEBUG StatusLogger Apache Log4j Core 2.18.0 initializing configuration XmlConfiguration[location=C:/----project path------/log4j2-tomcat.xml]
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Core' found 133 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Level' found 0 plugins
```

the above stdout logs are different in some manner as I noticed.
NOTE- log4j2-tomcat and log4j2-idp are my appenders and placed at same locations with their some use.

Can someone please find and help with error and tell how to solve that.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Nobody is asking to upload production code, but we can't help you without a [mcve], which can - and should - be simplified to _only_ document your problem and not contain anything else (no matter if it's proprietary or open source). Please check [ask]

Comment: What exact did your 'migration' involve? Just replacing a log4j 2.17.2 jar with a 2.18.0 version? Are you using a build tool like maven so you changed a dependency? Are all your dependent modules failing to log now or just some? You need to give some more details of what you have done to migrate.

Comment: Hi @JohnXF , I'm just replacing 2.17.2 to 2.18.0 . I'm using the gradle build. My all modules work fine and logs are getting printed for them. But only one module is not printing logs while upgrading.

Comment: You sure the offending module was definitely printing logs before upgrading the JAR? You sure nothing else changed in that module? I doubt the migration from 2.17.2 to 2.18.0 made any big changes to log4j that would cause it to stop logging. I would suspect that perhaps some configuration has changed (log levels, or perhaps location?) meaning you no longer see the logs.

Comment: @JohnXF Yes, the logs for offending module were printing fine along with other modules. But after upgrading, this module does not prints logs. NOTE: I made no other change, other than just writing 2.18.0 in place of 2.17.2 and building the gradle.

Comment: You need to troubleshoot the logging config for that module. Add the option `` -Dlog4j.debug=true`` to the java command running the application will write out startup-info about log4j and should help you see where it looks for configuration, where it finds it, etc. You could try adding the option to both the 2.17 and 2.18 versions of your application and compare/diff the output to see what changed.

Comment: @JohnXF thanks for the contribution. I will definitely look into this solution, and will try to resolve and update the same here. Thanks. By then please try adding the solutions everyone

Comment: @SaurabhPanchal: can you run your program with `-Dlog4j2.debug=true` and add the output of the status logger to your question (it's printed on `stdout`)? Also test with the latest version in case the problem has already been fixed.

Comment: Sure, I'm doing that. And will update the section here with status. Thanks for your suggestion @PiotrP.Karwasz

Comment: Hi, @OlafKock I have added the code with before and after difference after applying -Dlog4j.debug = true. Please help. I'm not able to print logs for IDP module in 2.18.0

Comment: Hi @JohnXF I have added the code with before and after difference after applying -Dlog4j.debug = true. Please help. I'm not able to print logs for IDP module in 2.18.0

Comment: Hi @PiotrP.Karwasz I have added the code with before and after difference after applying -Dlog4j.debug = true. Please help. I'm not able to print logs for IDP module in 2.18.0

Answer (score 1):

the problem is resolved. Thanks, everyone. But the actual thing that worked for me was -
adding -Dlog4j**2** worked for me. log4j is strict about '2' instead of just log4j for the latest versions like 2.18.0 and 2.19.0.